Conditions not apply on GCP PAM entitlements
I'm trying to set a condition on a GCP PAM entitlement that for example can be granted only on fridays, my expression is the below however it doesn't apply i can request and get the grant on any other days
For example I want to set a condition on one Entitlement saying that this role in that grant can only be granted on Friday
{
    "expression": "request.time.getDayOfWeek(\"Europe/Paris\") == 5"
}

Condition_image

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you sure that other roles you have do not grant the same permission as this one?

So I actually noticed that the entitlement is granted without any restrictions but the IAM roles are not granted because the condition wasn't met.
You can grant the roles/compute.viewer but when you go on compute you get a permissions error.
I guess google should block the granting of entitlements if the condition is not met , as it's not very clear right now
